# Sets of 72 elements with 3 subsets of 27, 27, and 18 elements

Tags: combinatorics

Background:

The 72 roots of the algebraic group E6 have one coordinatization in which there are three distinct subsets with 27, 27, and 18 coordinates.  See the section "Roots of E6" here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)

Question:

Can anyone think of another mathematical object which:

1. also happens to have 72 elements with distinct subsets of 27, 27,
   and 18 elements;
2. is UNRELATED to

   a. the algebraic group E6

   b. the polytopes $1_{22}$, $2_{21}$

   c. the 27 lines on the general cubic surface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three distinct sets are a feature of the projection.

The sets of 27 correspond to a tri-triangular prism.

The set of 18 correspond to three orthogonal hexagons.

If 'w' corresponds to a triangle, and -w its inversion, then

the 27 points here are (w,w,w) and the second as (-w,-w,-w)

The vertices of the 2_21 are (w,-w,0) cyclic, and (-w,w,0) cyclic.